# Hazelcast JCache on Liberty don't connect with other pods kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, hazelcast, kubernetes-networking

I configured hazelcast on Libery following this guide: https://openliberty.io/guides/sessions.html

It works smooth on my local machine:

```
[1/11/21, 9:53:26:362 GMT] 000000a0 com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.ClusterService                I [10.1.1.52]:5701 [appCluster] [3.12.6]

Members {size:3, ver:3} [
        Member [10.1.1.50]:5701 - c458c57e-4889-4f91-af6e-a531e13fe2ef
        Member [10.1.1.52]:5701 - e64784ce-a56a-4556-ab22-b2c2c3b65596 this
        Member [10.1.1.51]:5701 - 0432849f-7ec6-44b0-b888-0fd1e84c775b
]
```

But when I deploy it on cloud don't connect with other pods, like each pod have their own cluster.

```
[1/11/21, 10:05:36:444 GMT] 00000028 com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService                          I [172.30.203.92]:5701 [appCluster] [3.12.6] [172.30.203.92]:5701 is STARTING
[1/11/21, 10:05:39:099 GMT] 00000028 com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.ClusterService                I [172.30.203.92]:5701 [appCluster] [3.12.6] 

Members {size:1, ver:1} [
        Member [172.30.203.92]:5701 - 1c6e2c62-48ec-4659-86b9-17c871481907 this
]
```

Any clue about what can be causing this problem?

Answer (score 2):

To use Hazelcast on Kubernetes, you need to enable Hazelcast Kubernetes Plugin. Here are the resources that can help:

- [Hazelcast Kubernetes plugin documentation](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes)
- [Hazelcast Kubernetes Guide](https://guides.hazelcast.org/kubernetes/)
- [Hazelcast Embedded in Kubernetes Guide](https://guides.hazelcast.org/kubernetes-embedded/)

Comment: But is working in kubernetes local machine. Is there any diference with cloud?